# Module not found: Error: Package path ./react/swiper-react is not exported from package

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts, swiper.js

I upgraded to react-scripts v5, and I'm getting these errors:

This is how my imports look based on [Swiper documentation](https://swiperjs.com/react#usage-with-create-react-app):

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react/swiper-react';

import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css';
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
import { SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react/swiper-react.js';
```

to

```
import { SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
```

source
https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4003

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Rafal posted, another fix to your issue could be changing the following line

```
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css';
```

There are various different ways of importing the Swiper .css depending on what technologies you are using.

If you read the official documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/slides 
you can see all the different ways of importing  the css

> Not using Create React App? You can import the Swiper CSS from swiper/css instead.

So in my case where I am developing my app in Ionic, my import would look like this:

```
import 'swiper/css';
```

There are other options as well depending on how you are styling your sheets.

> For developers using SCSS or Less styles, Swiper also provides imports for those files.

> For Less styles, replace css with less:

```
import 'swiper/swiper.less';
```

> For SCSS styles replace css with scss:

```
import 'swiper/swiper.scss';
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
import 'swiper/css';
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved, import/extensions
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved, import/extensions
import 'swiper/css/pagination';

import clsx from 'clsx';
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved, import/extensions
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
```

Ignoring the eslint issues seems to make it work.